# Symfony2 Doctrine Qb STR_TO_DATE Unknown Function

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When i try to execute STR_TO_DATE mysql function with Doctrine query builder, symfony2 throws an exception like:

> Error: Expected known function, got 'STR_TO_DATE'

My code is :

```
STR_TO_DATE(m.metaValue, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '".$filter["sDate"]["month"]."/01/".$filter["sDate"]["year"]."' AND '".$filter["eDate"]["month"]."/01/".$filter["eDate"]["year"]."'"
```

How can i get it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `STR_TO_DATE` function is not available in DQL. See **[DQL Functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)**.

However you can make it available by installing **[`beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)** and adding this to your `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                # ...
                strtodate: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\StrToDate
```

Comment: I'v asked how can i get it work. :( Is there any way to get it work with DQL?

Comment: Added the information how to add the function to DQL to my answer :)

Comment: Hmmm i think this function is not available in Stof/DoctrineExtensions. I wonder if i install this ext. would it affect my current code?

Comment: `stof/doctrine-extensions` **`-bundle`** is a bundle to easily integrate `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` into your application while `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions` provides the classes for **additional** DQL functions. There is no interference between the two of them and as long as you don't configure doctrine to actually use some of these classes your application won't use them at all.

Comment: Ok thank you for information. I'm installing it now. I will accept your answer asap.