# unknow DQL function STR_TO_DATE

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I got this error **Expected known function, got 'STR_TO_DATE'**

my DQL Query :

```
public function findByPresta($prestataire){
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("STR_TO_DATE(c.datepresta,'%d,%M,%Y %h%i%s')")
            ->from($this->_entityName,'c');

        $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
        return $result;
    }
```

My Config.yml :

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                date_format: Dominos\VodBundle\DQL\Mysql\DateFormat
                strtodate: Dominos\VodBundle\DQL\Mysql\StrToDate
```

I need help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20494377/3675759

Comment: I have already seen this link and I did the same thing for DATE_FORMAT and it's work but not STR_TO_DATE

Comment: I solved this problem just replace strtodate by str_to_date